# Changing global variable using a function

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

I try to change a globally declared variable within a function. In Chrome developer tools I see that the variables change to the new values, but when the function is over and I use the variables later, the values are still the same.

Below I added my JavaScript code. The global variables are `color`, `width`, `height` and `radius`. In html there are input text-fields, in which the user enters the new values and fires the function "save" with a button onclick-event to change the global variables, which are used later (for drawing on Canvas).

Many thanks in advance for your help!! I really don't see the mistake :(

Please see below:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var color = "";
var width = 0;
var height = 0;
var radius = 0;

function save() {
    color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
}

function drawRectangle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,width,height);
}

function drawCircle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,100,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function showPicture() {
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200,200, width, height);
    };

    imageObj.src = 'miami.jpg';
}

var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

btn1.addEventListener("click", drawRectangle, false);
btn2.addEventListener("click", drawCircle, false);
btn3.addEventListener("click", showPicture, false);
```

Comment: Try calling `window['variableName']`.

Comment: What calls `save()`?

Comment: Are you sure `save` is called before `drawCircle` and `showPicture`? Maybe post the complete code. This code looks ok...

Comment: There's no binding to the save() function at the moment to any button. Stick some console.log code in your save() function to ensure that it's being called.

Comment: You could remove the save button entirely and simply use the latest values from the inputs directly from the draw functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! I already figured it out. The problem was that I had the input-text fields in form tags, which expected an action post/get method for PHP for further handling. That's the reason why the variables didn't keep the changed values.
After deleting this form tags everything worked out fine.

As I already described above the save() function is being called from the html-file onclick="save();", when I click the button to save the values.

Many thanks for your help.